# Prove that $\sum_{X=0}^N u(X) {N \choose X} p^X (1-p)^{N-X}=0 \iff u(X)=0, \space \forall X\in\{ 0,1,...,N \}$

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove that $Bin(N,p)$ where $N$ is fixed is a complete distribution.

Thus my goal is to show

$$E[u(X)]=0 \iff u(X)=0$$

While I was attempting to prove this I have noticed that

$$\sum_{X=0}^N u(X) {N \choose X} p^X (1-p)^{N-X}$$

is a degree-$N$ polynomial congruent to $0$ making all coefficients equal to $0$.

Here, the coefficients ends up being a nice linear combination which I suspect that it is a form of binomial coefficients.

For example, when $N=3$ I get the following

$$\begin{align} \sum_{X=0}^3 u(X) {3 \choose X} p^X (1-p)^{3-X}= \\
& \quad p^3*(u(3)-3u(2)+3u(1)-u(0)) \\ 
&+p^2*3(u(2)-2u(1)+u(0)) \\
&+p*3(u(1)-u(0)) \\
&+1(u(0))\\
\end{align}$$

$$ = p^3\sum_{i=0}^3u(i){3 \choose i}(-1)^i +p^2\sum_{i=0}^2u(i){2 \choose i}(-1)^i +p\sum_{i=0}^1u(i){1 \choose i}(-1)^i + u(0)$$

$$=\sum_{j=0}^3\sum_{i=0}^j u(i){3 \choose j}{j \choose i}(-1)^ip^j$$

The part that I would like have assistance is to show that

$$\sum_{X=0}^N u(X) {N \choose X} p^X (1-p)^{N-X}=\sum_{j=0}^N\sum_{i=0}^j u(i){N \choose j}{j \choose i}(-1)^ip^j$$

and that the cascades of $u(i)=0$ occurs, i.e., 
 $$u(0)=0 \implies u(1)=0 \implies ... \implies u(N)=0$$

I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: False if there is no assumption on $u$ and obvious if $u \geq 0$.

Comment: When you wrote $$\sum_{j=0}^3\sum_{i=0}^j u(i){j \choose i}(-1)^ip^j$$ I think you got things wrong. Because in your last expansion you got the terms with $p^2$ and $p$ having coefficient $3$, which you dropped in $$\sum_{j=0}^3\sum_{i=0}^j u(i){j \choose i}(-1)^ip^j.$$ Maybe you should correct your claim and try again.

Comment: Feng Shao: Thank you for noticing!  I will fix that.

Kavi Rama Murthy:  What I know is that $u(X)$ is a statistic of $X$ and my understanding is that it can literally be any function.  And our goal is to prove that it is necessarily equal to the $0$ function.  Can you elaborate on why it would be obvious if it is a non-negative function?  It might help me figure out the situation.

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\mathbb{E}}$Imagine if $u(X) = \left(-\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{X}$. This is an example of a non-zero function of $X$ that would have expectation $0$ (since $$\begin{align}\E\left[\left(-\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{X}\right] &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\left(-\frac{1-p}{p}\right)^{k}\binom{N}{k}p^{k}(1-p)^{N-k}\\  &= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{N} \binom{N}{k}(-(1-p))^k(1-p)^{N-k}\\ &= (-(1-p) + (1-p))^{N} \\ &= 0,\end{align}$$ using the binomial theorem.)

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Maybe in this case $p$ is not fixed? I don’t know about the completeness of a distribution. But having a look at OP’s description, he must think that $p$ is not fixed.

Comment: If $p$ is not fixed, then the original question becomes equivalent to showing that the [Bernstein polynomials are linearly independent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2761669/showing-bernstein-polynomial-is-a-basis).

Comment: Thank you, everyone.  Since $p$ is a probability it is assumed that $p\in [0,1]$.  From my approach the Bernstein Polynomial argument is the one that I was able to understand best, so I will stick to that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an answer that summarizes the question and the comments.

The goal is to show that

$$E[u(X)]=0 \iff u(X)=0$$

and the given equation is equivalent to

$$\sum_{X=0}^n u(X) {N \choose X} p^X (1-p)^{N-X} = \sum_{j=0}^N \sum_{i=0}^j u(i){N \choose j} {j \choose i}(-1)^ip^j = 0$$

We are assuming that $N$ is fixed and $p \in [0,1]$

The middle column is a Bernstein Polynomial that is a base, thus if it is equal to $0$ then $u(X)=0$.

This shows that $Bin(N,p)$ is a complete distribution.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is differentiate with respect to $p$.

If you assume that:

$$\forall p \in [0,1]  \:  \sum_{X=0}^N u(X) \binom N X p^X (1-p)^{N-X} $$

then you certainly have for $p=0$ that $u(0)=0$. So your first term disappears.

When you differentiate once, only the term $X=1$ where you differentiate $p^1$ once remains (you don't need to differentiate the $(1-p)^{N-1}$ because it's multiplied by $p^1$ which will give $0$ when you take $p=0$). So $u(1)=0$ and the second term disappears, and so on and so forth.

What you need to prove to make it work is that:
$$\frac{d^X}{dp^X}\left[p^X(1-p)^{N-X}\right]|_{p=0}=X!$$
and for all $Y>X$:
$$\frac{d^X}{dp^X}\left[p^Y(1-p)^{N-Y}\right]|_{p=0}=0$$

You can use Leibniz formula for a clean proof.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an elementary proof.

$\begin{array}\\
s(n, p)
&=\sum_{k=0}^n u(k) {n \choose k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n u(n-k) {n \choose n-k} p^{n-k} (1-p)^{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{j=0}^{k}u(n-k) {n \choose k} p^{n-j} \binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n \sum_{k=j}^{n}u(n-k) {n \choose k} p^{n-j} \binom{k}{j}(-1)^{k-j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^j\sum_{k=n-j}^{n}u(n-k) {n \choose k}  \binom{k}{n-j}(-1)^{k-n+j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^j(-1)^{n-j}\sum_{k=n-j}^{n}u(n-k) \dfrac{n!k!}{k!(n-k)!(n-j)!(k-n+j)!}(-1)^{k}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^j(-1)^{j}\dfrac{n!}{(n-j)!}\sum_{k=n-j}^{n}u(n-k)(-1)^{n-k} \dfrac{1}{(n-k)!(k-n+j)!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^j(-1)^{j}\dfrac{n!}{(n-j)!}\sum_{k=0}^{j}u(k)(-1)^{k} \dfrac{1}{(k)!(j-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^j(-1)^{j}\dfrac{n!}{j!(n-j)!}\sum_{k=0}^{j}u(k)(-1)^{k} \dfrac{j!}{(k)!(j-k)!}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^n p^j(-1)^{j}\binom{n}{j}\sum_{k=0}^{j}u(k)(-1)^{k}\binom{j}{k}\\
\end{array}
$

If $s(n, p) = 0$
for all $p$,
then,
since it is a polynomial in $p$,
all its coefficients 
must be zero.
Therefore
$\sum_{k=0}^{j}u(k)(-1)^{k}\binom{j}{k} = 0
$
for all $j$.
Starting with $j=0$,
this shows that
$u(k) = 0$
for all $k$.